# Blocking specific resources (css, images, videos, etc) using crawlee and playwright

Tags: node.js, apify, crawlee

I'm using `crawlee@3.0.3` (not released yet, from github), and I'm trying to block specific resources from loading with `playwrightUtils.blockRequests` (which isn't available in previous versions). When I try the code [suggested in the official repo](https://github.com/apify/crawlee/blob/47591ff766d378093023f1ef358a62d52380d6b6/packages/playwright-crawler/src/internals/utils/playwright-utils.ts#L253), it works as expected:

```
import { launchPlaywright, playwrightUtils } from 'crawlee';

const browser = await launchPlaywright();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await playwrightUtils.blockRequests(page, {
    // extraUrlPatterns: ['adsbygoogle.js'],
});
await page.goto('https://cnn.com');
await page.screenshot({ path: 'cnn_no_images.png' });
await browser.close();
```

I can see that the images aren't loaded from the screenshot. My problem has to do with the fact that I'm using `PlaywrightCrawler`:

```
const crawler = new PlaywrightCrawler({
    maxRequestsPerCrawl: 3,
    async requestHandler({ page, request }) {
        console.log(`Processing: ${request.url}`);
        await playwrightUtils.blockRequests(page);
        await page.screenshot({ path: 'cnn_no_images2.png' });
    },
});
```

This way, I'm not able to block specific resources, and my guess is that `blockRequests` needs `launchPlaywright` to work, and I don't see a way to pass that to `PlaywrightCrawler`.`blockRequests` has been available for `puppeteer`, so maybe someone has tried this before.

Also, i've tried ["route interception"](https://scrapingant.com/blog/block-requests-playwright), but again, I couldn't make it work with `PlaywrightCrawler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set any listeners or code before navigation by using [`preNavigationHooks`](https://crawlee.dev/api/browser-crawler/interface/BrowserCrawlerOptions#preNavigationHooks) like this:

```js
const crawler = new PlaywrightCrawler({
    maxRequestsPerCrawl: 3,
    preNavigationHooks: [async ({ page }) => {
        await playwrightUtils.blockRequests(page);
    }],
    async requestHandler({ page, request }) {
        console.log(`Processing: ${request.url}`);
        await page.screenshot({ path: 'cnn_no_images2.png' });
    },
});
```